# HTML flow different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, layout

I have a simple div example with two images one of which has absolute positioning inside the div.

That is my HTML code:

```
<div style="position: relative;  display: inline; "  >             
<img src="http://www.iphones.ru/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/iphone-girl-10.jpg" / >             
<img style="position: absolute;  top: -400px; left: 100px; z-index: 10" width="32"   height="32"  src="http://4geo.ru/images/other/icon-18plus.png"/>         
</div>
```

Try the example http://jsfiddle.net/yQn7W/1/ - you should see the "18+" logo on the face of the girl. 
It work's fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

But when I make few more divs one after another it seems that Firefox looses HTML flow and leaves "18+" image (which has "position: absolute;" attribute) on the page in the wrong place.

Try the example http://jsfiddle.net/yQn7W/2/

That's how it looks in the Chrome:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vhqe.jpg]

And that is what Firefox displays:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ4Ee.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either to width mismatch or because you haven't properly clearfixed the container. Since there is no live version of the problem I can't tell which is it, but if you clearfix the container and it doesn't work, you will have to set fixed width for each div, and also set it to float and inline-block, like so:

`<div style="position: relative; float:left; display: inline-block; width:500px;"  >`

Comment: I'm trying to make some experiment with clearfix right now, thank you for the tip.

But "float:left" is the solution i'm trying to avoid - it ruins all my HTML.

Comment: It won't ruin your html at all if you apply clearfix to the container of the floated divs! Its really easy too: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ . The width alone should work too, but its not proper if you need a fluid layout

Comment: Thank you very much! The _clearfix_ really helps with the _float:left_ so it's sovles the problem.